# g++.exe: error: libgomp-1.dll: No such file or directory; make: ***[Out-release] Error 1

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

I am trying to build a ReformAlign executable from a makefile.  I am using MINGW-64.  However I get the error message
g++.exe: error: libgomp-1.dll: No such file or directory
make: ***[Out-release] Error 1
what am I missing

Comment: Please show your makefile. Also, please provide more details about your environment

Comment: My operating system is windows 8 and I am using Mingw-64.bat; its g++ version is 7.2.0. My Makefile is called Makefile.windows and is as below

Comment: @N. Nabi. Makefile is too long so I will give it in sections

Comment: #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# This makefile was generated by 'cbp2make' tool rev.147                       #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


WORKDIR = %cd%

CC = gcc.exe
CXX = g++.exe
AR = ar.exe
LD = g++.exe
WINDRES = windres.exe
INC = 
CFLAGS = -fexpensive-optimizations -Os -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -lgomp -fopenmp
RESINC = 
LIBDIR = 
LIB = libgomp-1.dll
LDFLAGS =

Comment: INC_RELEASE = $(INC)
CFLAGS_RELEASE = $(CFLAGS) -O2
RESINC_RELEASE = $(RESINC)
RCFLAGS_RELEASE = $(RCFLAGS)
LIBDIR_RELEASE = $(LIBDIR)
LIB_RELEASE = $(LIB)
LDFLAGS_RELEASE = $(LDFLAGS) -s
OBJDIR_RELEASE = obj\\Release
DEP_RELEASE = 
OUT_RELEASE = bin\\Release\\ReformAlign.exe

OBJ_RELEASE = $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\AlignmentMetrics.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\FNW.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\FSequence.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\Profile.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\ReformAlignInitializer.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\main.o

Comment: all: release
clean: clean_release
before_release: 
 cmd /c if not exist bin\\Release md bin\\Release
 cmd /c if not exist $(OBJDIR_RELEASE) md $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)

after_release: 
 echo f | xcopy /f /y ReadMe.txt bin\\Release\\ReadMe.txt
 echo f | xcopy /f /y GPL-LICENSE.txt bin\\Release\\GPL-LICENSE.txt
 
release: before_release out_release after_release

out_release: before_release $(OBJ_RELEASE) $(DEP_RELEASE)
 $(LD) $(LIBDIR_RELEASE) -o $(OUT_RELEASE) $(OBJ_RELEASE)  $(LDFLAGS_RELEASE) $(LIB_RELEASE)

Comment: $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\AlignmentMetrics.o: AlignmentMetrics.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c AlignmentMetrics.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\AlignmentMetrics.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\FNW.o: FNW.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c FNW.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\FNW.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\FSequence.o: FSequence.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c FSequence.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\FSequence.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\Profile.o: Profile.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c Profile.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\Profile.o

Comment: $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\ReformAlignInitializer.o: ReformAlignInitializer.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ReformAlignInitializer.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\ReformAlignInitializer.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\main.o: main.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c main.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)\\main.o

clean_release: 
 cmd /c del /f $(OBJ_RELEASE) $(OUT_RELEASE)
 cmd /c rd bin\\Release
 cmd /c rd $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)

.PHONY: before_release after_release clean_release

Comment: I am sorry the Makefile is long and I had to give it is sections. I am actually a beginner and do not understand much about progamming.

Comment: You link your project to libgomp, do you have it installed?

Comment: I have checked it and have this error message; c:/mingw64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status;                                                      I do not what it means.

Comment: try this [link](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1027)

Comment: I had installed and used TDM-GCC with OpenMP but I still get the first error message

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the following dlls:
1. libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
2. libgomp-1.dll
3. libstdc++-6.dll
4. pthreadGC2.dll
from my compiler to the folder containing the makefile to generate the executable.

Thank you for the help and suggestions.